# Calculate total amount with VAT percentage inclusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, percentage, jsfiddle, calculated-columns

I have built an [*editable table*](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CBk5a/5/). There are two rows, one editable with *Textarea* and the other one editable with *Input number*. If you click on the column number, you can change the amount and you get automatically the Total sum.

There is also the possibility to clone new rows editable.

I am looking now on how to calculate the percentage (vat 21%) that automatically gives the TOTAl in my last row. I was looking for some examples but i have not found any.

As you can see in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Manna/CBk5a/5/) there  is a function which provide to calculate the total summing my `ID="sum"` in the rows.

My problem is which function i need to use to calculate the 21% VAT that then automatically gives me the new TOTAL in the last row with this percentage inclusive?

Hope the explanation is clear. [This](http://esempi.gabrieleromanato.com/jquery/jquery-totale-percentuale-sconto/) is only one example suitable i have found  but i can not apply in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is now updated. Check it now.

> http://jsfiddle.net/CBk5a/6/

Answer (score 0):

Just sum the column and multiply by 1.21.

Comment: Oh thanks! in case i would need to remove this percentage, how it would be?